# Джанго Функция сравнения данных http запроса с именем папки

Tags: django

Всем доброго времени суток!

Задумал сделать вывод изображений на страницах постов через сравнение http запросов и именами папок в которой лежат изображения. Папки с картинками лежат в  media.

У меня много постов и в каждом из них есть слайдер с картинками. Если это делать через добавление картинок в базу, то замучаешься, так как один пост содержит в слайдере до 40 изображений.

Есть несколько папок которые относятся к конкретному посту (папка post-1, post-2 и пт).

Нужна функция с условием:
Если  http запрос содержит post-1 (http://category-1/post-1), то выводить содержимое папки с именем post-1

Если не затруднит, помимо самой функции напишите плиз, как выводить данные из этой функции в шаблон.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Пишу сюда т.к. не могу оставить коммент.
Зачем делать сравнение адреса и имени папки? Как вы говорите: " через базу замучаешься". Я просто не вижу проблемы, можно сделать загрузку фотографий сразу по несколько штук или сразу по 40 изображений (тип, нажимаешь кнопку "добавить фотографии", открывается проводник, ты выделяешь до 50 фотографий и они загружаются). В шаблонах их можно вывести циклом for.
На мой взгляд, вывод из базы будет проще. Если сравнение адреса и имени папки еще можно сделать, то кажется, что дальше будет только интереснее с выводом картинок на сайт.

Comment: Хорошая идея ! Спасибо!